# Is it on-topic to ask questions about Wesnoth Markup Language (WML) and Battle for Wesnoth platform?

Tags: discussion, scope

It may sound a little strange, since [WML](https://wiki.wesnoth.org/ReferenceWML) (*Wesnoth Markup Language*, not *Wireless Markup Language*) is indeed a language, and [*The Battle for Wesnoth* open source game](https://www.wesnoth.org/) is also a game development engine.

This notwithstanding I searched for the word Wesnoth on SO and I found almost no post containing that word, and the few that did had only marginal relationships with WML and programming a game (either a scenario or a campaign) using WML on the Wesnoth engine.

Hence this question here on meta, just to avoid posting questions on this subject that will be deleted/migrated instantly.

Comment: As long as it's a programming question that otherwise follows the rules of the site, I don't see why not. This might also be useful: [Meta post regarding posting on Game Development versus Stack Overflow](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for the tip, but I thought GD.SE was only for professional and independent game devs, not for newbies/hobbyists in game development, so I ruled out that site from the start.

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with that SE, I just checked it out since I knew it existed. I missed that their bit stating who their audience is didn't include enthusiasts.

Comment: I would try to answer them if they appeared and I actually saw them. I will gladly make a tag if you cannot.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As a former WML hacker, I don't see much potential in bringing such questions here:

1. The global community of WML programmers is very small, and already has an established home at https://forums.wesnoth.org/viewforum.php?f=21
2. From my (admittedly dated) experience with WML, the main challenge is the peculiar syntax and the Wesnoth specific API, so there is hardly any overlap with other programming topics discussed on Stack Overflow.

That said, I do not object to WML questions posted here - I'd just be surprised if you got any useful answers.

Note that questions about Lua (which AFAIK you can also use for Wesnoth scripting and is probably a better fit for complex stuff) are most definitely on topic here (but again, I'd be surprised if you got useful answers about Wesnoth specifics).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. I've quite a bit of experience in Lua, but not in Wesnoth API, nor in WML. I'm a teacher trying to concoct some kind of long term project that would appeal to my students (technical high school with courses in programming and electronics). I think that explaining how a declarative language works by producing a Wesnoth scenario or, better, a campaign could be both interesting and enticing for them. BTW, I'm learning WML myself.

Comment: A similar language would be [tag:karel]. I first used Karel more than two decades ago, and promptly never used it again because it's a language designed specifically to teach programming. There's no practical use for Karel simply because no one needs to pick up virtual beepers on a 2D plane, but it still gets one or two questions a year when students take it for a spin. It may be low-yield, but is still a valid language.

Comment: I would try to answer them if they appeared.